# Force React component naming with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

There is React+TypeScript application, and all component classes should be upper-cased and have `Component` suffix, e.g:

```
export class FooBarComponent extends React.Component {...}
```

The application is ejected `create-react-application` application, i.e. is build with Webpack.

How can component naming be forced to be consistent with style guide, at least for component classes, with error being thrown on build when there are inconsistencies?

I believe this cannot be achieved with TSLint/ESLint alone. If different methods should be used for TypeScript and JavaScript, solutions for both languages would be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can offer you only solution for typescript.

> I believe this cannot be achieved with TSLint/ESLint alone.

There is a so-called rule [class-name](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/class-name/) that can solve your issue partially but seems you need to write custom rule for such case.

So let's try writing such [custom tslint rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/). For that we need to use `rulesDirectory` option in tslint config to specify path to custom rules

```
"rulesDirectory": [
    "./tools/tslint-rules/"
],
```

Since I'm going to write custom rule in typescript I will be using one feature that was added in [tslint@5.7.0](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/releases/tag/5.7.0)

> [enhancement] custom lint rules will be resolved using node's path
>   resolution to allow for loaders like ts-node (#3108)

We need to install `ts-node` package

```
npm i -D ts-node
```

Then add fake rule in tslint.json

```
"ts-loader": true,
```

and create file `tsLoaderRule.js` in our rulesDirectory:

```
const path = require('path');
const Lint = require('tslint');

// Custom rule that registers all of the custom rules, written in TypeScript, with ts-node.
// This is necessary, because `tslint` and IDEs won't execute any rules that aren't in a .js file.
require('ts-node').register({
    project: path.join(__dirname, '../tsconfig.json')
});

// Add a noop rule so tslint doesn't complain.
exports.Rule = class Rule extends Lint.Rules.AbstractRule {
    apply() {}
};
```

This is basically approach which is widely used in angular packages like angular material, universal etc

Now we can create our custom rule(expanded version of [class-name](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/rules/classNameRule.ts) rule) that will be written in typescript.

**myReactComponentRule.ts**

```
import * as ts from 'typescript';
import * as Lint from 'tslint';

export class Rule extends Lint.Rules.AbstractRule {
  /* tslint:disable:object-literal-sort-keys */
  static metadata: Lint.IRuleMetadata = {
    ruleName: 'my-react-component',
    description: 'Enforces PascalCased React component class.',
    rationale: 'Makes it easy to differentiate classes from regular variables at a glance.',
    optionsDescription: 'Not configurable.',
    options: null,
    optionExamples: [true],
    type: 'style',
    typescriptOnly: false,
  };
  /* tslint:enable:object-literal-sort-keys */

  static FAILURE_STRING = (className: string) => `React component ${className} must be PascalCased and prefixed by Component`;

  static validate(name: string): boolean {
    return isUpperCase(name[0]) && !name.includes('_') && name.endsWith('Component');
  }

  apply(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile): Lint.RuleFailure[] {
    return this.applyWithFunction(sourceFile, walk);
  }
}

function walk(ctx: Lint.WalkContext<void>) {
  return ts.forEachChild(ctx.sourceFile, function cb(node: ts.Node): void {
    if (isClassLikeDeclaration(node) && node.name !== undefined && isReactComponent(node)) {
      if (!Rule.validate(node.name!.text)) {
        ctx.addFailureAtNode(node.name!, Rule.FAILURE_STRING(node.name!.text));
      }
    }
    return ts.forEachChild(node, cb);
  });
}

function isClassLikeDeclaration(node: ts.Node): node is ts.ClassLikeDeclaration {
  return node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration ||
    node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ClassExpression;
}

function isReactComponent(node: ts.Node): boolean {
  let result = false;
  const classDeclaration = <ts.ClassDeclaration> node;
  if (classDeclaration.heritageClauses) {
    classDeclaration.heritageClauses.forEach((hc) => {
      if (hc.token === ts.SyntaxKind.ExtendsKeyword && hc.types) {

        hc.types.forEach(type => {
          if (type.getText() === 'React.Component') {
            result = true;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  return result;
}

function isUpperCase(str: string): boolean {
  return str === str.toUpperCase();
}
```

and finally we should put our new rule to `tsling.json`:

```
// Custom rules
"ts-loader": true,
"my-react-component": true
```

So such code as

```
App extends React.Component
```

will result in:

[image]

I also created **[ejected react-ts](https://github.com/alexzuza/react-ts-test)** application where you can try it.

### Update

> I guess tracking class names in grandparents won't be a trivial task

Indeed we can handle inheritance. To do that we will need create rule extended from class `Lint.Rules.TypedRule` to have access to `TypeChecker`:

**myReactComponentRule.ts**

```
import * as ts from 'typescript';
import * as Lint from 'tslint';

export class Rule extends Lint.Rules.TypedRule {
  /* tslint:disable:object-literal-sort-keys */
  static metadata: Lint.IRuleMetadata = {
    ruleName: 'my-react-component',
    description: 'Enforces PascalCased React component class.',
    rationale: 'Makes it easy to differentiate classes from regular variables at a glance.',
    optionsDescription: 'Not configurable.',
    options: null,
    optionExamples: [true],
    type: 'style',
    typescriptOnly: false,
  };
  /* tslint:enable:object-literal-sort-keys */

  static FAILURE_STRING = (className: string) =>
    `React component ${className} must be PascalCased and prefixed by Component`;

  static validate(name: string): boolean {
    return isUpperCase(name[0]) && !name.includes('_') && name.endsWith('Component');
  }

  applyWithProgram(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile, program: ts.Program): Lint.RuleFailure[] {
    return this.applyWithFunction(sourceFile, walk, undefined, program.getTypeChecker());
  }
}

function walk(ctx: Lint.WalkContext<void>, tc: ts.TypeChecker) {
  return ts.forEachChild(ctx.sourceFile, function cb(node: ts.Node): void {
    if (
        isClassLikeDeclaration(node) && node.name !== undefined &&
        containsType(tc.getTypeAtLocation(node), isReactComponentType) &&
        !Rule.validate(node.name!.text)) {
      ctx.addFailureAtNode(node.name!, Rule.FAILURE_STRING(node.name!.text));
    }

    return ts.forEachChild(node, cb);
  });
}
/* tslint:disable:no-any */
function containsType(type: ts.Type, predicate: (symbol: any) => boolean): boolean {
  if (type.symbol !== undefined && predicate(type.symbol)) {
    return true;
  }

  const bases = type.getBaseTypes();
  return bases && bases.some((t) => containsType(t, predicate));
}

function isReactComponentType(symbol: any) {
  return symbol.name === 'Component' && symbol.parent && symbol.parent.name === 'React';
}
/* tslint:enable:no-any */

function isClassLikeDeclaration(node: ts.Node): node is ts.ClassLikeDeclaration {
  return node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration ||
    node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ClassExpression;
}

function isUpperCase(str: string): boolean {
  return str === str.toUpperCase();
}
```

See also commit:

- https://github.com/alexzuza/react-ts-test/commit/98ea77fa5a1f4fc73c53a055deb6960a3e7f3afe

Comment: Thanks, that's an excellent example of TSLint plugin. I guess tracking class names in grandparents won't be a trivial task (will be a lesser problem because they aren't that common in React).

Answer (score 7):

This is lot easier to do in `eslint`. The custom plugin is a lot less complex. So I created a plugin showcasing the same. To test the plugin I created the below file

```
import React from "react"

class ABCComponent extends React.Component {

}

class ABC2component extends React.Component {

}

class TestComponent {

}


class FooBarComponent extends React.Component {

}

class fooBazComponent extends React.Component {

}

class FooBazing extends React.Component {

}
```

And then ran the plugin on the same

[image: Plugin results]

I followed the below guides while writing the plugin

https://flexport.engineering/writing-custom-lint-rules-for-your-picky-developers-67732afa1803

https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/27/writing-custom-eslint-rules/

https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules

The final code I come up with was below for the rules

```
/**
 * @fileoverview Check that proper naming convention is followed for React components
 * @author Tarun Lalwani
 */
"use strict";

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Rule Definition
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var toPascalCase = require('to-pascal-case');

module.exports = {
    meta: {
        docs: {
            description: "Check that proper naming convention is followed for React components",
            category: "Fill me in",
            recommended: false
        },
        fixable: "code",  // or "code" or "whitespace"
        schema: [
            // fill in your schema
        ]
    },

    create: function(context) {

        // variables should be defined here

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Helpers
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        // any helper functions should go here or else delete this section

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Public
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        return {

            ClassDeclaration: function(node) {
                var isReactComponent = false;
                if (node.superClass && node.superClass && node.superClass)
                {
                    if (node.superClass.object && node.superClass.object.name == 'React' && node.superClass.property.name === 'Component')
                        {
                            isReactComponent = true;
                        }
                    else if (node.superClass && node.superClass.name === 'Component') {
                        // if you want to suppot extends Component instead of just React.Component
                        isReactComponent = true;
                    }
                }

                if (isReactComponent) {
                    var className = node.id.name;
                    if (className[0] !== className[0].toUpperCase() || !className.endsWith("Component"))
                         context.report({
                            node: node, 
                            message: "Please use Proper case for the React Component class - {{identifier}}",
                            data: {
                                identifier: className
                            }, fix: (fixer) => {
                                var newClassName = className.toLowerCase().replace('component', '') + 'Component';
                                newClassName = toPascalCase(newClassName);
                                return fixer.replaceTextRange(node.id.range, newClassName)
                            }
                        });

                }
            }

        };
    }
};
```

The key is to understand the AST Tree, which I did using [astexplorer](https://astexplorer.net/). Rest code is quite self explanatory.

I have hosted the plugin on below repo in case you want to give it a short directly

https://github.com/tarunlalwani/eslint-plugin-react-class-naming

Install the plugin using below command

```
npm i tarunlalwani/eslint-plugin-react-class-naming#master
```

Then add it to your .eslintrc

```
{
    "plugins": [
       "react-class-naming"
    ]
}
```

Then add the rules in .eslintrc

```
"rules": {
   "react-class-naming/react-classnaming-convention": ["error"],
   ....
}
```

Comment: Great example. Thanks for publishing it on NPM, hope it will be useful.