# Specify PascalCase Naming Convetion for Variables of JSX.Element Type in eslint Rules

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'd like to enforce PascalCase for variables of type `JSX.Element` in my React+Typescript project. I frequently use the following pattern to create functional components, and I like to distinguish my eponymous export by giving it a PascalCase name:

```ts
//MyComponent.tsx
//PascalCase for MyComponent 
export const MyComponent= (): JSX.Element =>{  
  return (
    <div>
      My Component
    </div>
  )
}
export default MyComponent
```

With my current linter settings, I get a warning that `` Variable name `MyComponent` must match one of the following formats: camelCase, UPPER_CASE ``. How can I add a rule to my linter settings that will enforce PascalCase for variables of type JSX.Element?

Here's my current `.eslintrc.json`:

```js
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "react-hooks"],
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
      "warn",
      {
        "allowExpressions": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "pragma": "React",
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is not currently possible at the point of declaration (see link below). However, the incorrect casing can't proliferate beyond the file in which it is declared, as lowercase names are reserved for intrinsic types like `div`, `span`, etc.

```
// my-component.tsx
export const myComponent: FC<{}> = () => (
  <div>My Component</div>
);

export default myComponent;
```

```
// app.tsx
import { myComponent } from './my-component';

// Fails to compile with: Property 'myComponent' does not
// exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.  TS2339
const App = (): JSX.Element => <myComponent />;
```

In the case of a default export, the name used in the declaring file is effectively erased, as it's simply assigned to whatever name is chosen in the importing file:

```
// app.tsx
import SomeOtherName from './my-component';

const App = (): JSX.Element => <SomeOtherName />;
```

---

Discussion about not having a rule specific to React components here: [typescript-eslint/issues/2607](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2607)

> Additionally - there's no guarantee that a function that returns a
> JSX.Element is in fact a react component. Utility functions that
> return JSX.Element, but aren't react components are a relatively
> common practice, which would cause false-positives.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but an important part of the question is enforcing the PascalCase naming rule for ```const MyComponent: FC<{}>``` in the eslint rules. Could you add that to your answer?

Comment: Hrmm, maybe my assumption was incorrect. I was thinking that the reason was that it was seeing it as a regular function rather than a component, e.g. similar to `const Test = () => 234;`. Updating answer.

Comment: Ok but you have no thoughts on the linter settings portion of this question?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in the other comment. I just meant that I (incorrectly) thought that the react eslint plugin would be providing special rules for react components, overriding the typescript eslint plugin's normal preference that functions be `camelCase`.

Answer (score 0):

I think eslint doesn't have settings for such case, but You can create custom rule and apply it. Please check following link for the same.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49225308/13162789

Comment: The issue with a rule like this is that it's common and valid to have a helper function that returns JSX that are not rendered Components. It could likely be enforced on things explicitly declared as `React.FC`, but you can't just assume that anything that returns `JSX.Element` is a component.